# How does RequireJS decide what to run and what to load?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs

I'm running an `EmberJS` app using `RequireJS`

In my `routes.coffee` file I'm defining my routing:

```
define ['jquery'
        'ember'
        '_'
        'cs!myapp/myapp'
        "cs!myapp/routes/index_route"
        ], ($, Ember, _, MyApp, IndexRoute) ->
    alert "Inside myapp route"
    MyApp.Router.map () ->
        @resource "play", path: '/play', () ->
            @resource "myapp", {}, () ->
                @resource "games", {}, () ->
                    @route "next"
                    @resource "frames", {}, () ->
                        @route "commercial"
                    @resource "trivia", {}, () ->
                        @route "commercial"
                @route "start"
                @route "howItWorks"
                @route "goodbye"
        @route "readyToStart"
        @route "noContent"

    MyApp.IndexRoute = IndexRoute
```

Specifically, as I understand it, that's a `define` not a `require`, so it shouldn't execute that code. But the alert goes off. So what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the `define` you show in your answer won't immediately call the factory function you give to it. (The factory function is the callback you give to `define`.) However, the `alert` in `routes.coffee` will be called as soon as something requires `routes.coffee` either directly or indirectly. The `routes.coffee` module is required if it appears in the dependency list of a `require` call or of a `define` call.

Note that it is possible to require a module and not use it. RequireJS does not care whether the module is *used* or not. It only cares that a module is required. So a call like `require(['foo'])` will require the module `foo` and cause its factory function to be called even though it is not *used* in this `require` call.

Comment: My `routes.coffee` is used in a `define` of a `main.coffee`, so does that mean it runs just by being in a `define`?

Comment: Yes. When RequireJS loads `main.coffee`, it reads the list of dependencies passed to the `define` call, which you say contains `routes.coffee`, so it loads `routes.coffee`, which causes its factory function to be called and `alert`. However, it is not the `define` call which is **in** the `routes.coffee` that causes its own factory function to be executed. The factory function of a `define` is always caused to be executed by *another* `define` or by a `require` call.